# d3.js | Change map tiles

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, openstreetmap

I have a d3.js based map example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797
Is it possible to change tile source to openstreetmap (For example: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/mobile-navigation.html)? As I need house numbers also.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5593150)?

Comment: I have seen but how to integrate openstreet map layers?

Comment: You can use leaflet for example, see [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/using-multiple-maps-with-leafletjs.html).

Comment: I'm using it now but would like to replace leaflet with D3.js

Comment: You mean you would like to replace leaflet with openlayers?